# What happened to the ability to dismiss flags while looking at the flagged post?

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

I see that new buttons got rolled out in the moderator flags view on Programmers (and elsewhere?) today. I love them. They're pretty cool.

However, I often look at the question before really deciding what to do about it. Sometimes I check the comments or answers before making the final decision whether to close a question or not. If we get a general "moderation attention needed" flag and the post ends up closed, we no longer have the ability to dismiss the flag while looking at the post and have to go back to the overall flags view and use one of the buttons.

Can we have the flag dismissal links back in the flag display panel shown when we as moderators browse to a question that's been flagged?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dismiss buttons should have still been in the bottom panel; their disappearance was.... well, a bug. They should reappear as soon as I can fix them and deploy them.